# How to sort a glossary by order of appearance?

Tags: glossaries, sorting

In the **glossaries** package, how can I make the glossary print the entries by order of appearance?

Some context: I'm using the glossaries package to generate a symbol index, and I'm interested to see whether the order in which I introduce the notation makes sense.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suspect the package option `sort=use` will do what you're after, i.e. write `\usepackage[sort=use]{glossaries}`. From the [manual](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#x1-160002.4):

> **sort**
>
> This is a `⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩` option where the option can only have
>   one of the following values:
>
> - `standard`: entries are sorted according
>     to the value of the sort key used in `\newglossaryentry` (if present) or
>     the name key (if sort key is missing);
> - `def`: entries are sorted in
>     the order in which they were defined (the sort key in
>     `\newglossaryentry` is ignored);
> - `use`: entries are sorted according to
>     the order in which they are used in the document (the sort key in
>     `\newglossaryentry` is ignored).
>
> The default is `sort=standard`.

Comment: Thanks! I was using version 2, which didn't support this option yet. I upgraded to version 3 and it works as expected.